# How can I get one entities Id and set it to another table's foreign key ? Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, algorithm, hibernate

I want to get Id of randomly selected `employee`. And set it to employee_id to `employeeOfMonths` table. How can I do that at ServiceImplemantation part ?

Employee :

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name="national_id")
    private String nationalId;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @NotBlank
    private String surname;

    private Integer salary;

    @Column(name="start_date")
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date startDate;

    private String office;

    private String department;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "employee",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<EmployeeOfMonths> employeeOfMonths;

}
```

EmployeeOfMonths :

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "employeeofmonths")
public class EmployeeOfMonths{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="employee_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private Employee employee;
}
```

EmployeeRepository :

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository <Employee,Integer>, QueryByExampleExecutor<Employee> { }
```

EmployeeOfMonthRepository :

```
public interface EmployeeOfMonthsRepository extends JpaRepository <EmployeeOfMonths,Integer> {
}
```

EmployeeServiceImp :

```
  @Override
    public EmployeeDTO selectEmployee(Employee employee) {
        List<Employee> all = employeeRepository.findAll();
        Random randomizer = new Random();
        Employee random = all.get(randomizer.nextInt(all.size()));
   

        return EmployeeMapper.toDto(random);
        }
```

Controller :

```
 @Scheduled(cron = "0 15 10 15 * ?", zone = "Europe/Istanbul")
    @GetMapping(path="/month")
    public EmployeeDTO selectEmployee(Employee employee){
        return employeeService.selectEmployee(employee);
    }
```

Comment: INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_MONTH (ID, MONTH, YEAR) VALUES (idVal, currMonth, currYear); -> something like that, I would imagine

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your EmployeeOfMonths Entity first.
And than just add via the repo.

```
@Override
public EmployeeDTO selectEmployee(Employee employee) {
    List<Employee> all = employeeRepository.findAll();
    Random randomizer = new Random();
    Employee random = all.get(randomizer.nextInt(all.size()));

    employeeOfMonthsRepository.save(new EmployeeOfMonths(random))

    return EmployeeMapper.toDto(random);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you but it adds only Primary Key. employee_id is null

Comment: Just to assert as early as possible, add `@ManyToOne(optional = false)` and lomboks ´@NonNull´ to your EmployeeOfMonths.
Have you debugged and you are sure that ´random´ contains an employee?
Can you turn on SQL Logging? https://www.baeldung.com/sql-logging-spring-boot

Comment: I added these two but still same. Yes it contains employee. It randomly select and returns with "EmployeeMapper.toDto(random);" on postman.

Comment: Btw when I implemented that save method it wanted a constructor in class. So I added one empty.